# I am trying to print via Ethernet on a thermal printer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, printing, ethernet

I am trying to print via Ethernet on a thermal printer in VB.NET. Searching the internet, I found this routine, which apparently stored in memory print because the printer does nothing. Then, if I issue a test page from the control panel, it prints what I printed above + test page. Do you miss something in the routine?, Thank you very much the help that you can give me.

```
Dim cImpresion As String = Chr(27) & Chr(77) & Chr(64)
Dim tcpSender As TcpClient = New TcpClient()

tcpSender.SendBufferSize = 4096
tcpSender.Connect(whatIP, whatPort)
If tcpSender.Connected = False Then
  tcpSender.Close()
  Exit Sub
End If

Dim nStream As NetworkStream = tcpSender.GetStream()
If nStream.CanWrite = True Then
  Dim SendBytes As Byte
  SendBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("the text I want to print")
  nStream.Write(SendBytes, 0, SendBytes.Length)
  nStream.Flush()
End If

nStream.Close()
tcpSender.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding VbCrLf to SendBytes:

```
SendBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("the text I want to print")
SendBytes = SendBytes + vbCrLf
```

Or use nStream.WriteLine instead of nStream.Write